# How can I get the values which only contains alphanumeric values?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

I have 2 columns of object datatype like

```
col1             col2  
AB               AB123
BC123            SG
BG274            HF
DC               DG789
DG156            HD
```

I want my output to be like

```
 output
                                                                                                   BC123
BG274
DG789
DG156
```

I have tried rg expression and I am getting my col1 as my output

Comment: I have 2 columnns where col1 contains values of String+numbers and only string values. Also with my col2 where col2 contains values of String+numbers and only string values. I want my output col to be String+numbers values from col1 and string+number values from col2

Comment: Is there always at least one column with the correct pattern?

Comment: Please mention your DBMS name.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can mask the data and `fillna`:

```
m1 = df['col1'].str.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z]+\d+')
m2 = df['col2'].str.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z]+\d+')

(df['col1'].where(m1)
 .fillna(df['col2'].where(m2))
 )
```

Generic method for an arbitrary number of columns:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']

df[cols].where(
  df[cols]
 .apply(lambda s: s.str.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z]+\d+'))
 ).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Output:

```
0    AB123
1    BC123
2    BG274
3    DG789
4    DG156
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your database query:

(For SQL Server)

To select alphanumeric values from col1

```
select col1 from table1 where col1 like  '%[A-Za-z]%' and col1 like '%[0-9]%'
```

To select unique alphanumeric values from col1 and col2

```
create table table1(col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50));
insert into table1 values('AB','AB123');
insert into table1 values('BC123','SG');
insert into table1 values('BG274','1');
insert into table1 values('DC','DG789');
insert into table1 values('DG156','HD');
```

Query:

```
select col1 from table1 where col1 like  '%[A-Za-z]%' and col1 like '%[0-9]%'
  union
select col2 from table1 where col2 like  '%[A-Za-z]%' and col2 like '%[0-9]%'
```

Output:

| col1 |
| --- |
| AB123 |
| BC123 |
| BG274 |
| DG156 |
| DG789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ZqhFmgV)

For MySQL:

Query:

```
    select col1 from table1 where col1 regexp '[A-Za-z][0-9]'
      union
    select col2 from table1 where col2 regexp '[A-Za-z][0-9]'
```

Output:

| col1 |
| --- |
| BC123 |
| BG274 |
| DG156 |
| AB123 |
| DG789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uSo0LUCR)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with regx

```
def regex_filter(val, rex):
    if val:
        mo = re.search(rex, val)
        if mo:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
df[df['col1'].apply(lambda x : regex_filter(x,"[A-Z]+[0-9]+"))]['col1']
Out[103]: 
1    BC123
2    BG274
4    DG156
```